# Why does python/ numpy += behave like this with arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)
x = np.reshape(x, (4,5))
dW = np.zeros(x.shape)
dWhy = dW
dW += np.sum(x)
dWhy += x
```

Why do the two methods results in the same result (dW = dWhy), when

```
dW = dW + np.sum(x)
dWhy = dWhy + x
```

does not?

Answer (score 2):

Because `dWhy = dW` makes them the same array. `+=` is not a redefinition (reassignment), it changes the values inplace.

```
dW += np.sum(x) # affects both since they are the same object
dWhy += x  # affects both since they are the same object
```

Unless you redefine (reassign) one of them later.

```
dW = dW + np.sum(x) # redefines dW
dWhy = dWhy + x # redefines dWhy
```

Another way to make `dW` and `dWhy` 2 different arrays that can then be changed inplace independently with `+=` would be to define `dWhy = dW.copy()` at the start.

Comment: I would say *"same **object**"* for clarity ;)